# Creating Multiple ERC721 Tokens

Tags: truffle, ganache

Imagine you wright your own token following the ERC721 standard. Now you want to create 10,000 tokens of this type.

- Do you need one contract to manage each token?
- Do you have to deploy 10,000 token contracts?
- Can you manage all tokens with one single contract?

The use case I was thinking about was creating for example 10,000 baseball cards, each one different. Then let users to trade, buy and sell. So, for the creator of the tokens, how would this be managed? I believe that using a recursive function will cost a lot of gas...

Thanks a lot

Comment: you can manage everything in one contract. the sell , buy and trade would be similar to erc20. Howerver your question need more details and should have a problem to solve :)

Answer (score 1):

ERC115 standard outlines a smart contract interface that can represent any number of fungible and non-fungible token types.
[ETHEREUM EIP 1155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1155.md)

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you mentioned, `baseball cards`, can be implemented in a single `ERC721`  smart contract. The `ERC721` standard is practically tailor-made for such cases.

Yeah, each card would contain different data `Different Player`, but the "size" of all the cards would be the same, their format too. (Some could be duplicates if you want, not an issue).

**In short:**

- No, in your case, you need a single `ERC721` contract to manage all
  NFTs of that type `baseball cards`
- Again, no. One ERC721 can manage all 10,000 of your baseball cards. Including the transaction, trading, selling, and exchanging the cards. And, likely, most of the other functionalities you might need too.
- Yes, all of the `baseball card` NFTs could be managed by a single
  contract.

In a project where I am hired as a contractor, I manage MILLIONS of NFTs/tokens containing different data, all using a single ERC721 contract.

In your case, minting all those 10,000 cards might be expensive.
But you can sort of bypass that by using `ERC721A` standard.

NOTE: I would **STRONGLY** advise against "inventing" your own `ERC721` or `ERC721A` contract. Better instead to use the `OpenZeppelin` library for such an implementation. It's audited and checked by thousands upon thousands of developers for any issues and extremely optimized.